# Removing Text from Case Description

Tags: apex, trigger, text

I created the following trigger to extract lead information coming into Salesforce from G2. I have been able to extract the value that comes after each line that I declare using contains but I need help deleting the prefix words of each line.

For example, I need help deleting the text '*Email: *' - I would think the Line Remove function would do it, but when the record save it continues to copy the "*Email: *" portion + the name of the submitter

Here is my code - thank you all as this is my first apex trigger:

```
trigger GrabCaseDescriptionText on Case (before insert, before update)  {
for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
    if (c.Description != null) {
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();
        lines = c.Description.split('\n');
        
        for (String line: lines) {
            if(line.contains('*EMAIL: *')){
                line.remove('*EMAIL: *');
                system.debug(line);
                c.CaseEmailAddress__c = line;
            }
             if(line.contains('*NAME:* ')){
                line.remove('*NAME:* ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Submitter_Name__c = line;
            }
            if(line.contains('*ACTION TAKE ON G2:* ')){
                line.remove('*ACTION TAKE ON G2:* ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Action_Take_on_G2__c = line;
            }
            if(line.contains('*INDUSTRY:* ')){
                line.remove('*INDUSTRY:* ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Industry__c = line;
            }
            if(line.contains('*COMPANY SIZE:* ')){
                line.remove('*COMPANY SIZE:* ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Company_Size__c  = line;
            }
            if(line.contains('*COMPANY:* ')){
                line.remove('*COMPANY:* ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Submitter_s_Company__c  = line;
            }
            if(line.contains('PHONE NUMBER: *')){
                line.remove('PHONE NUMBER: *');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Submitter_s_Phone__c  = line;
            }
            
            
        }
        if(c.CaseEmailAddress__c !=null){
            List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email=:c.CaseEmailAddress__c LIMIT 1];
            if(cons.size()>0)c.ContactId=cons[0].id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove those substrings from the `Description`, or only the fields you copy data into?

Comment: I believe only the fields I copy data into. Because when this triggers, the email field I am copying from description into a new field called CaseEmailAddress will come out as  *EMAIL: *andrewinfo@gmail.com

And therefore, I just want the new field CaseEmailAddress to say andrewinfo@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

In Apex, strings are immutable. This means that no string method will modify an existing string, but instead will return a new copy of the string with the desired operation applied.

That means your code should look like:

```
c.CaseEmailAddress__c = line.remove('*EMAIL: *');
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! If I become a contributing member to this forum I will say that you were my first inspiration lol - this gives me hope for my Apex journey

Comment: @andrew thanks! Your first question is definitely higher quality than most, I'd think you'd be a great contributor. 